# codeigniter curl library with https get request

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, https

```
$this->load->library('Curl');

$url = 'https://example.com/data.php';

echo $this->curl->simple_get($url);
```

This is the code i use to get response via codeigniter curl library and i get nothing when it running. 
But it working well with HTTP.

Is there any way to do with HTTPS for this?

Comment: please post full cURL response you are getting. If response if blank then try to look at cURL error.

Comment: Have a look at this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738204/how-would-you-run-a-get-request-via-curl-on-an-ssl-enabled-website